Which episodes of Friends is this?
I'm trying to remember which episode of Friends this was. I looked up the list of episodes names on Wikipedia with no results.
Informations about the episode:

It's for sure not in seasons 6 through 10, as I just rewatched them and could not find it.
I don't remember all the 6 friends stories, but I clearly remember Joey's (which is why I want to rewatch it with my brother). Joey is participating in a TV event, a fund raising or auction or something like that (something that requires the participants to answer phone calls). Joey agrees (or encouraged to do it) because he will be showing his face on camera (which is good for him because he is an actor). But the spot they gave him was off camera (mostly), or was blocked by someone/something, so he started looking for someone to switch places with him so he can be fully seen. I don't know what happened next, but at the end he started fighting some other participant, on live TV, for not wanting to switch places with him.
Joey seemed to be eager to appear on TV. So I would say it's definitly either before he got the part of DR. Drake Ramoray (before episode 2 of season 2, according to Wikipedia) or after they killed his character (after episode 18 of season 2).

Does this ring a bell? Any help is much appreciated.

It's the One where Phoebe hates PBS.
Season 5 Episode 4

Joey wears a tuxedo believing he's hired as host for a PBS telethon,
  but is actually just hired as one of many phone operators on screen,
  even sitting outside the main camera view.


Yep, that's the one. Thanks!
